# passing an object to a delegate

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function to do an API call.  I want to pass an object through that function to my delegate methods, so that I have flexibility on showing a success/error message.

This object can be a Label, a string, maybe even JSON if I want to go there.

```
 public delegate void ifItWorks(theParameter[] delegateParms, 
    ref object delegateObject);

 public delegate void ifItThrows(theParameter[] delegateParms, 
    ref object delegateObject);

 public static void apiCall(string yourCredentials, 
    theParameter[] yourParms, ifItWorks sendSuccess, ifItThrows sendAlert,
    ref object yourObject)
```

How do I make this work?  I'm fighting the compiler to figure this out.

The usual errors I get are

> A ref or out argument must be an assignable

or

> Delegate has some invalid arguments

Comment: Can you please show code that fails with error you described (please also make sure to provide exact error and not some interpretation of one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API method can just ignore whatever the delegate needs and let the caller of your method use a closure to capture whatever object(s) they need.

```
public static void apiCall(string yourCredentials, Action sendSuccess, Action sendAlert)
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
        sendSuccess()
    }
    catch
    {
        sendAlert();
    }
}
```

The caller can then write:

```
var someObject = CreateAnObjectINeed();
apiCall(credentials, () => DoSomething(someObject), () => HandleError(someObject);
```